# How to extract an Ethernet Drivers Install content and use in a WEC7 image?

Tags: windows, networking, embedded, windows-ce, drivers

[Building the Windows Embedded Compact 7](http://www.embedded101.com/Blogs/SamuelPhung/tabid/72/entryid/207/Compact-7-Getting-Started-Part-3-Develop-an-OS-Design.aspx) image in Visual Studio 2008.

Tired building the image and using the general nc200 Ethernet drivers but did not appear to work.

Would like to support Ethernet connectivity on the Intel NUC DCCP847DYE.

It uses, the Intel 82579V Gigabit Ethernet Controller LAN: [Intel® Gigabit Ethernet Controller Windows 7 driver for Intel® NUC](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Desktop%20Boards&ProductLine=Intel%C2%AE%20NUC%20Boards%20and%20Kits&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE%20NUC%20Kit%20DCCP847DYE)

How do I get these drivers built into the WCE7 OS image?

Is there a way to extract the contents and use as part of my project?

Can I install it on the running image?

How do I get Ethernet functionality built into a WEC7 image?

**EDIT**

[Intel® Ethernet Drivers for Microsoft* Embedded Operating Systems](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=22928&ProdId=3619&lang=eng)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 drivers will be of no use.  You need Windows CE drivers.  I don't see them for the 82579 on [the Intel download site](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Ethernet%20Components&ProductLine=Ethernet%20Controllers&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE%2082540EM%20Gigabit%20Ethernet%20Controller).  You might try the 8254x driver to see if, by luck,it works.

I also see on the [Windows Embedded resource page](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/drivercatalog.aspx?fsr=1&WEItemsPerPage=10&WEPageNumber=67) that a CE 6.0 driver should be available for the 8257x chips, specifically as E1E51CE6.dll so searching for that might be useful.

Comment: can you please point me in the right direction on how to include a DLL into the image?

Comment: Do a search for "windows ce bib files"